# jQuery AutoComplete - how to open the Autocomplete div where the user is typing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery autoComplete plugin. Is it possible to open the autocomplete div where the user is typing? Right now if I have an input that is width 500px, the autocomplete div opens with a width of 500px. I changed that to 150px. and would like to position the autocomplete div near where the user is typing.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you using [jQueryUI's Autocomplete widget](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Position Utility:

```
$("#some-element").autocomplete( "option", "position", { my : "right top", at: "right bottom" } );
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position